# Replace a specific character with empty value if it occurs for at least 2 times continuously using python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas data frame column having values like this:

```
col1
cat + + + + + ind
dog + + + + + + uk
lion + + + us
tiger + aus
```

I want to replace those '+' with '' where '+' occurs for at least 2 times

Final output will be

```
 col1
 cat ind
 dog uk
 lion us
 tiger + aus
```

How do do it in most efficient way using python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex:

```
result = df['col1'].str.replace('(\+\s?){2,}', '')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0        cat ind
1         dog uk
2        lion us
3    tiger + aus
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

The pattern `(\+\s?){2,}` means match two or more plus symbols that can be followed by a whitespace.